# Python - Extracting audio from video files to numpy array using ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-python

I want to use `python` & `ffmpeg-python` to extract the audio from a video directly into numpy array.

Currently, I first dump the audio as a `wav` file using ffmpeg through CLI and read it back to Python using scipy.io.wavefile

```bash
$ ffmpeg -y -i {source_file} -qscale:a 0 -ac 1 -vn -threads 1 -ar 16000 out.wav
```

Followed by this snippet in python

```py
_, audio1 = wavfile.read("out.wav")
```

Now I want to modify the above as

```py
out, err = (
    ffmpeg
        .input(in_filename)
        .output(
            '-', format='s16le', 
            acodec='pcm_s16le', 
            ac=1, 
            ar='16k', 
            # sample_rate='16000',
            **{"qscale:a": 0}
        )
        # .overwrite_output()
        .run(capture_stdout=True, capture_stderr=True)
)

audio2 = np.frombuffer(out, dtype=np.int16)
```

(Ref: https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/blob/master/examples/transcribe.py#L23)

However, when I compare `audio1` and `audio2`, I see that the number of samples are different as well as the values. For the same file, when I read through `wavefile`, the signal has values in range [-221, 212], but the second approach yields values in range [-74, 72].

I also tried to plot the signal (starting 1 sec, 16000 samples) and it seems, there is some issue with delay and amplitude.[image: figure1]

A closer look at the starting shows that there are also some `0` values at the beginning when I use `wavfile`

[image]

The starting delay seems to be around 320 samples.

Finally, the number of samples in both the arrays also seems to be different:

```py
>> print(audio1.shape, audio2.shape)
(2091648,)), ((2091008,)
```

Comment: in python you have `format='s16le', acodec='pcm_s16le'` but maybe this makes difference? OR maybe you should write `audio2` to file and read with `wavfile` to check if `wavfile` doesn't makes modifications. Or maybe it changes when you use `frombuffer( ..., dtype=np.int16)`

Comment: Did some more digging and found this:
My `source_file`, when give to CLI `ffmpeg` as already converted to `avi` while the `source_file` I used inside python script was the original `mp4`. This difference in format is causing the issue I guess. But the `avi` file I use is converted from original using `ffmpeg -y -i {source_file} -qscale:v 2 -threads 1 -async 1 -r 25 {avi_file}`, so must contain same data. Ideally, what I want is to directly take in `mp4` and work with it.

Comment: It seems like the original `mp4` is using `encoder: Lavf58.29.100` while after conversion, the new `avi` file is using `software        : Lavf59.27.100`. Does this change the PCM extraction process?

Comment: I don't know if `Lavf` is loosless or not. if it is not loosless then reconverting from one version to another could change it. You would have to test it on your own